# Powershell - How To Parse URL from RSS Feed, Convert to JSON

Tags: json, powershell

i want to parse URLs from this RSS Feed in Powershell.
https://endpoints.office.com/version/worldwide?clientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7&allVersions=true&format=RSS

For Example this one: https://endpoints.office.com/changes/Worldwide/2020092900?singleVersion&clientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7

However, i do not get the Json-File as a result.

How can i get the JSON-File with Powershell?

Comment: Which exactly is your problem? Parsing the urls? Or returning the json from each url?

Answer (score 2):

RSS is just XML, so we can offload fetching and parsing of the feed to the [`Invoke-RestMethod` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-5.1):

```bsh
$feedEntries = Invoke-RestMethod 'https://endpoints.office.com/version/worldwide?clientRequestId=b10c5ed1-bad1-445f-b386-b919946339a7&allVersions=true&format=RSS'
```

Converting the resulting objects to JSON is as easy as grabbing the desired properties with `Select-Object` and piping the results to `ConvertTo-Json`, at which point you can output to a file with `Set-Content`:

```bsh
$feedEntries |Select-Object title,link |ConvertTo-Json |Set-Content output.json
```